# hovered elements to be displayed in a text box

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

I have written a script that highlights hovered elements with a 2px red outline, I need the hovered elements to be displayed in a text box below. Is there any possibility?

Thanks in Advance !

```
function inspectorMouseOver(e) {
    var element = e.target;
    element.style.outline = '2px solid #f00';
    last = element;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by displaying inside a textbox? Pleas elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @usama : Fetch the contents of the web page and display it externally in another control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer

```
function inspectorOnClick(e) 
{
    var element = e.target;
    alert(element.innerHTML);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Thanks for your Suggestions friends!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery function to achieve this:

Example code:

```
$( "#elementId" ).mouseover(function() {
  $(this).css({'display': 'inline-block','background-color': '#ff0000', 'color': '#ffffff'})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add border on hover then simply do

```
 function inspectorMouseOver(e) {
    e.style["border"] = '2px solid #f00';
 }
```

and call the function as

```
  <div class="myDiv" onmouseover="inspectorMouseOver(this)" > TEST  </div>
```

here i have called the function on mouse over and passed this as parameter. so you will get the corresponding Node in your function then add style. let me know if that helps.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/g3g7c7ky/1/ is this what you wanted?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="ul1">

<li>123</li>
<li>456</li>
<li>789</li>
<li>1010</li>
</ul>

<input type="text" class="txtbox">
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ul1').on('mouseover','.ul1 li', function(){
  var txt =$(this).text();
  console.log(txt);
  $(this).css('border','2px solid #f00');
    $('.txtbox').val(txt);
  });

  $('.ul1').on('mouseout','.ul1 li', function(){

  $(this).css('border','none');
  });
});
```

Comment: you can achieve the highlighting part with CSS too